# log_e printing variables in arduino

Tags: arduino

I'm using Arduino with esp32 and a board called WiPhone. I'm trying to make a calculator, but I keep messing up and I want better debug messages. I know it's a stupid question, but how do I print variables with log? (such as log_e, log_i, etc.)

I tried just doing `log_e(variable);` but Arduino said `"expected ')' before 'variable'."`

Comment: The first parameter to the `log_X()` functions has to be a string.  That string can contain formatting characters that cause additional parameters to be included in the message: for example, `log_e("The value of the variable is %d", variable);` (assuming that `variable` is an int).